# TFS Build specific changeset and deploy it using the changeset number

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, changeset

I have a Build Definition to build a solution on my TFS.
This works well, but it always builds the latest version.

1. How can I force to build a specific changeset from the past?
2. How can I use/pass this number to the "MSBuild Arguments" to use it there for deployment?

Comment: In what way would the changeset number be used for deployment?

Comment: I want to use it for the deploy path:

/p:DeployIisAppPath=/changeset/CHANGESETNUMBER

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to your first question is clearly what @Dylan has stated.

To your second part:
The important argument is `GetVersion`.
Navigate to activity "Run MSBuild for Project" within your Build Process Template, by default this has a value `CommandLineArguments` equal to

`String.Format("/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true {0}", MSBuildArguments)`

You can change it to something like

`String.Format("/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true {0} /p:DeployIisAppPath=/changeset/{1}", MSBuildArguments, GetVersion)`

and get where you need to go.

Comment: Creating a new template is the way to go. I only had to change "GetVersion" into "BuildDetail.SourceGetVersion" to get the latest build version :-)

Comment: My current *Build process file* is set to *TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.xaml*, however I can't find that file in the *BuildProcessTemplates* folder.

Answer (score 28):

When you queue up the build from Team Explorer, in the Parameters tab one of the Advanced arguments is get version.

Note: I think you need to specify this in the form C123  where 123 is the changeset number.

Comment: thank you ... that anwsered the first question ... but how can I pass this parameter (C1234) to the MSBuild Arguments to use it for deployment?

Comment: It's in one of the workflow arguments, you can access that when setting the arguments passed to the msbuild (you'd have to customize the build workflow)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the changeset number, then it will only make sense for CI builds, since they typically build a single changeset.

For any other kind of build, I recommend using the build ID, which is unique, and covers the case of a build that builds multiple changesets.